# Setting timeouts with Google Cloud Storage JSON API

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm writing some bytes to gcs and would like to use the JSON API wrappers provided by Google, but with a timeout. Currently I have this:

```
storage = new Storage
            .Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport...)
StorageObject storageObject = new StorageObject().setBucket(bucket).setName(path);
Storage.Objects.Insert insertObject =
                storage.objects().insert(bucket, storageObject, content).setName(path);
insertObject.execute();
    }
```

Is there a simple way to add a timeout to either `CloudStorage`, `StorageObject` or the `.execute`?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the storage abstraction `import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage` has a way to [set timeouts on initialization](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/storage/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/storage/Storage.Builder.html#setHttpRequestInitializer%28com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer%29) with [HttpRequestInitializers](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.19.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer) separate from your credentials.

If you have a `MyGCSAbstraction` that you create for each GCS operation, you can do the following:

```
private static HttpRequestInitializer setHttpTimeout(final HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer) {
    return new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {
            requestInitializer.initialize(httpRequest);
            httpRequest.setConnectTimeout(1000); // ms
            httpRequest.setReadTimeout(1000); // ms
        }
    };
}

MyGCSAbstraction(String applicationName, Credential credential) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    Builder builder = new Storage.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), setHttpTimeout(credential));
    builder.setApplicationName(applicationName);
    storage = builder.build();
}
```